# How can I impelement the satellite mkmapview like ios6

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, ios6

This is kind of a weird question. In iOS6 if you open a map pin, you can see a view with a header where a map is in satellite mode and making circles around the place of the map pin. Is there any way I can achieve this programatically?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't loaded iOS 6 yet so I'm guessing at the appearance you're describing. If there is a static satellite image at the top of your screen you'd need to find a source of satellite imagery. The Google Static API License says you can only use their static imagery in webpages (i.e. not apps) and I'm not aware of Apple offering static maps (i.e. outside of an MKMapView). So you might need to put a small MKMapView at the top and then turn off user interaction with it, either programmatically or using Interface Builder.